# non-blocking zmq send / recv and process when all replies received

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I am building a simple client-server app with python and zmq.

The objective is the following: From a client I would like to simultaneously send (non-blocking) requests to multiple servers and when the all the responses received, to be notified in order to make several calculations.

Until now, all the zmq examples which I found and applied, are blocking in the socket.recv of every request until response from each server received. This means that I am able to send my request to multiple servers but I am doing this on serial way and lose some valuable time.

The attempts I made are based at the following:
https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html

Do you have any material/examples regarding my question?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, in your client, you create a REQ socket for each server. The ZeroMQ guide describes how to [handle multiple sockets](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Handling-Multiple-Sockets) and provides an example in Python.

Comment: The above link is not workin when I clicked on the link. Please update.

Comment: thank you! now it is working completely perfect,